# How to override for() to get geographic coordinates from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
      import pandas as pd

      df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Paris', 'New York', 'Rio'],
               
               'Point': [(48.853638186045075, 2.3164768734228094, 0.0),
                         (40.73149967161843, -73.99345738955843, 0.0),
                         (-22.925268779593164, -43.23729165751779, 0.0)]
               })

      print(df)

      # Output:

      City               Point
      Paris             (48.853638186045075, 2.3164768734228094, 0.0)
      New York          (40.73149967161843, -73.99345738955843, 0, 0)
      Rio               (-22.925268779593164, -43.23729165751779, 0.0)
```

I need to separate the geographic coordinates from latitude and longitude. So I made the following code:

```
      df['lat'] = 0
      df['long'] = 0

      for i in range(0, len(df)):
         df['lat'].iloc[i] = df['Point'][i][0]
         df['long'].iloc[i] = df['Point'][i][1]

      print(df)

      # Output:

      City               Point                                      lat          long
      Paris       (48.853638186045075, 2.3164768734228094, 0.0)    48.853638     2.316477
      New York    (40.73149967161843, -73.99345738955843, 0, 0)    40.731500    -73.993457
      Rio         (-22.925268779593164, -43.23729165751779, 0.0)   -22.925269   -43.237292
```

The implementation is working perfectly. However, I would like to remove the for() to make the operation more efficient. How can I remove for()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols = ['lat','long']
df[cols] = df['Point'].apply(lambda p: pd.Series([p[0],p[1]],index=cols))
```

Explanation:
Convert each Point tuple into a Series, the result of the apply method is a DataFrame. Assign the result as new columns to `df`.

Comment: I tried to execute your implementation suggestion, but the following error appears: "ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies 3."

Comment: So one of your Point tuples were of length four then. I'm adjusting the code accordingly.

Comment: Worked perfectly! It was a typo I made. Tks

Comment: Hi! In a first test it worked. However, now the following error appears: TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'.
Do you know what it could be?

Comment: Oh yeah, the `index` kwarg should be for the Series construction. I fixed the code, it should work now.

Comment: In another dataframe, there are some 'Points' that are 'None'. The following error appears: NoneType object is not subscriptable. Do you know how I can resolve this?

Comment: you need to drop those rows first. Either of these methods should work: `df.dropna(subset=['Points'])` or something like: `df[~df['Point'].isNull()]`

Comment: Is there a way to keep the dataframe complete even if some 'lat' or 'long' is None?

Comment: oh yeah, actually in the lambda function above, you can create the Series only if the not-null condition is met. So it would bel like `lambda p: None if p[0] is None else pd.Series([p[0],p[1]],index=cols)`